# Overriding hashcode with OR condition

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hashcode, pojo

I am writing a pojo , where I am overriding hashcode and equals ,
But my condition for making objects equal is having a OR condition .In this case how to write hashcode ???

For example, I have a pojo, having three fields like aaa,bbb,ccc 
and condition of treating equal is , **aaa must be equal and either bbb or ccc should be equal**.I wrote this in equals overriding section but what to write in hashcode in this case ???

```
public class POJO {

private String aaa;
private String bbb;
private String ccc;

///How to use or condition here ???????
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((aaa == null) ? 0 : aaa.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((bbb == null) ? 0 : bbb.hashCode());
    return result;
}
//my condition is aaa and (bbb or ccc) should be equal
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    POJO other = (POJO) obj;
    if (aaa == null) {
        if (other.aaa != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!aaa.equals(other.aaa))
        return false;
    if (bbb == null || ccc == null) {
        if (other.bbb != null || other.ccc != null)
            return false;
   //This is the main condition
    } else if (!bbb.equals(other.bbb) || !ccc.equals(other.ccc))
        return false;
    return true;
}
public String getAaa() {
    return aaa;
}
public void setAaa(String aaa) {
    this.aaa = aaa;
}
public String getBbb() {
    return bbb;
}
public void setBbb(String bbb) {
    this.bbb = bbb;
}
public String getCcc() {
    return ccc;
}
public void setCcc(String ccc) {
    this.ccc = ccc;
}




}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `equals` logic is inconsistent, so you can't define a consistent `hashCode`.

Suppose you have 3 objects with the following values :

```
   aaa    bbb  ccc

   "a1"  "b1"  "c1"
   "a1"  "b1"  "c2"
   "a1"  "b2"  "c2"
```

According to your logic, the first object is equal to the second (both the aaa and bbb properties are equal), and the second is equal to the third (both the aaa and ccc properties are equal), but the first is not equal to the third (since both the bbb and ccc properties are not equal). `equals` must be transitive.

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null
>   object references:
>
> - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x)
>     should return true.
> - It is symmetric: for any non-null reference
>     values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if
>     y.equals(x) returns true.
> - **It is transitive: for any non-null
>     reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and
>     y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.**
> - It is
>     consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple
>     invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently
>     return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on
>     the objects is modified.
> - For any non-null reference value x,
>     x.equals(null) should return false.

Answer (score 0):

The contract of hashCode function is the following (from javadoc):

> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>     execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>     return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>     comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>     consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>     of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the
>     equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the
>     two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required
>     that if two objects are unequal according to the
>     equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>     each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>     However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>     integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>     hash tables.

If your code satisfy the three conditions your code is correct.